# Idioms Quiz of 23

Tags: idioms, puzzle

Idioms Quiz of 23Q for Idiom lovers

Q1. 小华的爸爸是围棋高手，你在他面前夸耀自己的棋技，不是____吗？

Q2. 自从那次火灾后，村民一听到孩子的惊叫就_____以为又是哪一家失火了。

Q3. 世界上没有_____的事情，要成功就应该付出努力。

Q4. 这个电视剧向人们提出一个 _____的问题：中学生应该追求什么？

Q5. 小女孩由于找不到妈妈，______地坐在地上哭了起来。

Q6. 我的手表就放在桌上，怎么会_____呢？

Q7. 由于_____的战争，使得这个国家元气大伤，人民流离失所。

Q8. 我和小军从小，就是好朋友，______他送我的每件礼物，我都珍藏着。

Q9. 如果一个人做事情总是______,他就永远享受不到成功的欢乐。

Q10. 要学一门语言必须_____三天打鱼，两天晒网是学不好的。

Q11. 为了将罪犯一网打尽，我们这次的行动千万要保密，不能______。

Q12. 做事应该_______, 循序渐进;急于求成反而容易失败。

Q13. 你们公司的产品______,怎能打入国际市场呢？

Q14. 他是一个_____的法官，不会为一点小利而忘记了自己的职责。

Q15. 爸爸的生意虽然多次失败但他_____,愈挫愈勇，终于取得了事业上的成功。

Q16. 他听到自己中了头奖，一时______, 结果一脚踩空，从楼梯摔了下去。

Q17. 那几个年轻人_____, 整日花天酒地，你离他们远点。

Q18. 公司经营状况这么差，你得找出症结所在,_____, 才有可能改善。

Q19. 他虽然病得很重，但还没有到_____的地步。

Q20. 一个人要有远大的目标，那种______混日子的思想行为是要不得的。

Q21. 他贪污公款，以为神不知鬼不觉，结果_____, 被判坐牢。

Q22. 十年树木，_____, 培养人才并不是一件容易的事。

Q23. 听说逃犯逃审到了这一区，居民一时间_____人人自危。

A. 爱屋及乌 B. 按部就班 C. 百年树人 D.百折不挠 E.班门弄斧 F.半途而废 G. 杯弓蛇影 H. 不二法门 I. 不胜枚举 J.不务正业 K. 不翼而飞 L. 不自量力 M. 不耻下问 N. 不可救药 O. 不劳而获 P. 不知所措 Q. 草木皆兵 R. 长年累月 S. 持之以恒 T. 出类拔萃 U. 出人头地 V. 唇亡齿寒 W. 粗制滥造 X. 打草惊蛇 Y. 大公无私 Z. 当仁不让 AA. 德高望重 BB. 得过且过 CC. 得意忘形 DD. 掉以轻心 EE. 东窗事发 FF. 东山再起 GG. 对症下药 HH. 耳濡目染 II. 发人深省

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 小华的爸爸是国棋高手，你在他面前夸耀自己的棋技，不是**班门弄斧**吗？
2. 自从那次火灾后，村民一听到孩子的惊叫就**杯弓蛇影** 以为又是哪一家失火了。
3. 世界上没有**不劳而获**的事情，要成功就应该付出努力。
4. 这个电视剧向人们提出一个**发人深省**的问题：中学生应该追求什么？
5. 小女孩由于找不到妈妈，**不知所措** (惊惶失措)地坐在地上哭了起来。
6. 我的手表就放在桌上，怎么会**不翼而飞**呢？
7. 由于**长年累月**的战争，使得这个国家元气大伤，人民流离失所。
8. 我和小军从小就是好朋友，**爱屋及乌**，他送我的每件礼物，我都珍藏着。
9. 如果一个人做事情总是**半途而废**，他就永远享受不到成功的欢乐。
10. 要学一门语言必须**持之以恒**，三天打鱼，两天晒网是学不好的。
11. 为了将罪犯一网打尽，我们这次的行动千万要保密，不能**打草惊蛇**。
12. 做事应该**按部就班**，循序渐进；急于求成反而容易失败。
13. 你们公司的产品**粗制滥造**，怎能打入国际市场呢？
14. 他是一个**大公无私** (公正廉明) 的法官，不会为一点小利而忘记了自己的职责。
15. 爸爸的生意虽然多次失败但他**百折不挠**，愈挫愈勇，终于取得了事业上的成功。
16. 他听到自己中了头奖，一时**得意忘形** (乐极忘形)，结果一脚踩空，从楼梯摔了下去。
17. 那几个年轻人**不务正业**，整日花天酒地，你离他们远点。
18. 公司经营状况这么差，你得找出症结所在,**对症下药**, 才有可能改善。
19. 他虽然病得很重，但还没有到**不可救药** (病入膏肓；无药可救) 的地步。
20. 一个人要有远大的目标，那种**得过且过**混日子的思想行为是要不得的。
21. 他贪污公款，以为神不知鬼不觉，结果**东窗事发**， 被判坐牢。
22. 十年树木， **百年树人**， 培养人才并不是一件容易的事。
23. 听说逃犯逃审到了这一区，居民一时间**草木皆兵**，人人自危。